# I Got Stuck with "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in Firebase, I am trying to create File Operation with Android Studio, I got stuck with this error.

My Error Code

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.ptpai.rekamedik, PID: 28972
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type Model.EditHasilLabModel
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                      at com.ptpai.rekamedik.HasilLab$1.onDataChange(HasilLab.java:69)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

HasilLab.java

```html
package com.ptpai.rekamedik;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Helper.HasilLabAdapter;
import Model.EditHasilLabModel;

public class HasilLab extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth mAuth, otentikasi;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    ListView listView;
    List<EditHasilLabModel> list;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    HasilLabAdapter Adapter;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hasil_lab);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        // Inisialisasi Objek Otentikasi Firebase
        otentikasi = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //Cek jika user sudah memiliki login
        if (otentikasi.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            //Akhiri Sesi
            finish();
            //Alihkan Ke Login
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Masuk.class));
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Sedang Memuat...");
        progressDialog.show();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(user.getUid()).child("HasilLab");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                list.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    EditHasilLabModel EditHasilLabModel = snap.getValue(EditHasilLabModel.class);
                    list.add(EditHasilLabModel);
                }
                Adapter = new HasilLabAdapter(HasilLab.this,R.layout.hasil_lab_data_items,list);
                listView.setAdapter(Adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

HasilLabAdapter.java

```html
package Helper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import Model.EditHasilLabModel;

import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.ptpai.rekamedik.R;

import java.util.List;


public class HasilLabAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EditHasilLabModel> {

    FirebaseDatabase adapterFirebase;
    Activity activity;
    int resource;
    List<EditHasilLabModel> list;

    public HasilLabAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, List<EditHasilLabModel> list) {
        super(activity, resource,list);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        adapterFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource,null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.getImages);
        TextView NamaHasilLab = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.getNamaHasilLab);
        TextView KeteranganHasilLab = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.getKeteranganHasilLab);

        NamaHasilLab.setText(list.get(position).getNama_Hasil_Lab());
        KeteranganHasilLab.setText(list.get(position).getKeterangan_Hasil_Lab());
        Glide.with(activity).load(list.get(position).getImageUri()).into(imageView);

        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_hasil_lab.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ptpai.rekamedik.HasilLab">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My EditHasilLabModel.java

```html
package Model;


/**
 * Created by dskymc on 14/03/2018.
 */

public class EditHasilLabModel {
   private String Nama_Hasil_Lab;
   private String Keterangan_Hasil_Lab;
   private String imageUri;

    public EditHasilLabModel(String Nama_Hasil_Lab, String Keterangan_Hasil_Lab, String imageUri) {
        this.Nama_Hasil_Lab = Nama_Hasil_Lab;
        this.Keterangan_Hasil_Lab = Keterangan_Hasil_Lab;
        this.imageUri = imageUri;
    }

    public EditHasilLabModel() {

    }

    public String getNama_Hasil_Lab() {
        return Nama_Hasil_Lab;
    }

    public void setNama_Hasil_Lab(String Nama_Hasil_Lab) {
        this.Nama_Hasil_Lab = Nama_Hasil_Lab;
    }

    public String getKeterangan_Hasil_Lab() {
        return Keterangan_Hasil_Lab;
    }

    public void setKeterangan_Hasil_Lab(String Keterangan_Hasil_Lab) {
        this.Keterangan_Hasil_Lab = Keterangan_Hasil_Lab;
    }

    public String getImageUri() {
        return imageUri;
    }

    public void setImageUri(String imageUri) {
        this.imageUri = imageUri;
    }

}
```

Database Structure

```html
User
  userID
    Hasil_Lab:
         ImageUri
         Keterangan_Hasil_Lab
         Nama_Hasil_Lab
```

Please help me, I am trying to debug, I think the Adapter maybe wrong, but I don't know where is it.

Thanks for any Help really appreciated.

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: This is my Database Structure
http://i65.tinypic.com/5b4m86.png

Thanks for Advance

Comment: No, *add* database structure, not *link* it. Meaning *add it to question*.

Comment: Already add the database structure in a question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference hasilRef = rootRef.child("User").child(uid).child("HasilLab");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String imageUri = dataSnapshot.child("imageUri").getValue(String.class);
        String keterangan = dataSnapshot.child("keterangan_HasileLab").getValue(String.class);
        String nama = dataSnapshot.child("nama_Hasil_Lab").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", imageUri + " / " + keterangan + " / " + nama);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
hasilRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

There is no need to use `getChildren()` method.

Comment: Why are you using strings instead of the `EditHasilLabModel`?

Comment: @AndréKool To be sure that the OP can get the results from the database for sure. See how his model class looks like? The fields are not correctly named, only one is correct, `imageUri`. Firebase is always looking for fields like this while deserializing. This field `Nama_Hasil_Lab` should be named: `namaHasilLab` and the coresponding getter: `getNamaHasilLab()`. That's why I used the String class.

Comment: Thanks for the advance, But while I am try the code, the activity is always loading and never open.

Comment: What does this line of code return `Log.d("TAG", imageUri + " / " + keterangan + " / " + nama);`?

Comment: Looks like it load the data correctly in database, but none show at activity... Only Loading Image ( Sedang Memuat... )

03-14 20:47:47.771 12476-12476/com.ptpai.rekamedik D/TAG: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rekamedik-74eca.appspot.com/o/Images%2FmNNKMvZ9h4gmCWWl8ikrAdoT4Ew1%2Fimages%2F1521010383059.jpg?alt=media&token=1d106b5a-e9fc-4c8f-ac90-c656f3c72129 / 123456 / Pemeriksaan Darah

Comment: Do you have the desired data in your logcat?

Comment: So those names appear in the logcat, right?

Comment: Yes, it Appears on the logcat bro

Comment: but the activity can't start... Sorry iam new in android dev and also firebase :) :)